# InstanceNotFoundException when trying to discover queues in Hermes JMS

Tags: jms, activemq-classic

I have active MQ and Hermes JMS.

The JMX connector for active mq is enabled in `activemq.xml`:

```
<managementContext>
   <managementContext createConnector="true"/>
 </managementContext>
```

But when I try to discover queues on the active mq session in Hermes JMS I get `InstanceNotFoundException` exception:

```
javax.management.InstanceNotFoundException: org.apache.activemq:BrokerName=localhost,Type=Broker
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.getMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:1095)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.getAttribute(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:643)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.getAttribute(JmxMBeanServer.java:678)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1464)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:97)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1328)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1420)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.getAttribute(RMIConnectionImpl.java:657)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:322)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:177)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:174)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:173)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:556)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:811)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:670)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(StreamRemoteCall.java:275)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:252)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:161)
    at com.sun.jmx.remote.internal.PRef.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl_Stub.getAttribute(Unknown Source)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector$RemoteMBeanServerConnection.getAttribute(RMIConnector.java:902)
    at hermes.ext.activemq.ActiveMQAdmin.discoverDestinationConfigs(ActiveMQAdmin.java:140)
    at hermes.impl.HermesAdminAdapter.discoverDestinationConfigs(HermesAdminAdapter.java:82)
    at hermes.impl.DefaultHermesImpl.discoverDestinationConfigs(DefaultHermesImpl.java:1126)
    at hermes.browser.tasks.DiscoverDestinationsTask.invoke(DiscoverDestinationsTask.java:77)
    at hermes.browser.tasks.TaskSupport.run(TaskSupport.java:175)
    at hermes.browser.tasks.ThreadPool.run(ThreadPool.java:170)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

I am using `Hermes 1.14` and `Active MQ 5.9`

Answer (score 1):

`Hermes JMS` uses `JMX` to discover queues on the broker.

Apache 5.8 changed the name of `JMX MBeans` which means Active Mq won't find the MBeans it is looking for (hence instance not found exception). I tried discovering queues with Active MQ 5.1 and it worked.

There is nothing you can do to fix it. The author of Hermes JMS would have to update the code to support Active MQ 5.8+

MBeans in ActiveMQ 5.1:
[image]

MBeans in ActiveMQ 5.9:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is correct, that HermesJMS doesn't support ActiveMQ >=5.8 . However there is one repository fork, which has this change implemented:
https://github.com/paoloantinori/HermesJMS

I have just installed the .jar from the repository and it works. So anybody with the same issue of connecting SoapUI -> HermesJMS -> ActiveMQ higher than 5.8, use the JAR from GIT repo above.